# Array.find and native asyncawait/async / asyncawait/await solution

Tags: javascript

The following:

```
h = hs.find(h => await(isAvail(h)));
```

Uses the following libraries:

```
const async = require('asyncawait/async'); // async is used in the isAvail function to wrap it
const await = require('asyncawait/await');
```

I can't seem to find a elegant way of doing without an old school for loop array. Problem is is that when find iterates over the array await seems to block it. This does not happen with native awaits since await requires that the function is declared as async, which itself returns a Promise which you must await and so fourth.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you try to clarify what you want to achieve rather than just stating what you think the problem is?

Comment: @E.Sundin Hi! I'd like to remove the third party libraries. Iterate through an array and return the first element which matches "true" after the element is sent as an argument to a async function (isAvail). I'd like to skip iterating through the entire array.

Comment: If you run it async then the conception of what is `the first element` is pretty fuzzy.

Comment: @E.Sundin Running asynchronous operations doesn't imply running them concurrently. You can run them in sequence and still benefit from freeing up the event loop for other things.

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone You're right, of course.

Comment: @E.Sundin I enjoy stating the obvious LOL

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
h = hs.find(async h => await(isAvail(h)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a for loop *somewhere*.

Here's a solution using the `asyncawait` library:

```
const async = require('asyncawait').async;
const await = require('asyncawait').await;

const find = async(function (arr, predicate) {
  let check = false, result = null;
  for (let elm of arr) {
    check = await(predicate(elm));
    if (check) {
      result = elm;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
});

function isItBig (n) {
  return Promise.resolve(n > 3);
}

let test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

find(test, isItBig).then(console.log);  //prints 4
```

This is an almost identical solution using the native async/await included in recent versions of node.js:

```
async function find (arr, predicate) {
  let check = false, result = null;
  for (let elm of arr) {
    check = await predicate(elm);
    if (check) {
      result = elm;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

async function isItBig (n) {
  return n > 3;
}

let test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

find(test, isItBig).then(console.log); //prints 4
```